# Moment.js and formatting on server side

Tags: meteor, momentjs

Need to know:

- I'm using the latest version of meteor
- I'm using the latest version of moment.js
- This code is on the server side

---

```
var date = moment(new Date());
console.log(date.format("YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss.SS"));
```

---

I end up with this error

```
SyncedCron: Exception "count daily parks per spot" ReferenceError: moment is not defined
    at spotIDList.forEach (app/server/main.js:66:18)
    at SynchronousCursor.forEach (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:1054:16)
    at Cursor.(anonymous function) [as forEach] (packages/mongo/mongo_driver.js:876:44)
    at Object.job (app/server/main.js:62:16)
    at packages/percolate_synced-cron.js:242:26
    at scheduleTimeout (packages/percolate_synced-cron.js:290:7)
    at packages/percolate_synced-cron.js:338:42
    at Meteor.EnvironmentVariable.EVp.withValue (packages/meteor.js:1186:26)
    at packages/meteor.js:502:25
    at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor.js:1238:24)
```

---

the snippet above comes from the following code

```
SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Simple Cron Function',
  schedule: function(parser) {
    // parser is a later.parse object
    return parser.text('every 15 second');
  },
  job: function(intendedAt) {
    var spotList = spots.find({});

    spotList.forEach((spot) => {

      var devaddr = `${spot.devaddr}`;
      var date = moment(new Date());
      console.log(date.format("YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss.SS"));
      var dailyVisitsCount = log.find(
        {
          devaddr : devaddr,
          car : "1",
          createdAt: {
            $gte: date.format("YYYY-MM-DD  HH:mm:ss.SS")
          }
        },
        {
          sort: {
            createdAt:1
          }
        }
      ).count();

      spots.update({devaddr : devaddr}, { $set: {numberOfParksToday: dailyVisitsCount } } , {multi: false}, function(err, res) {
        if (err) throw err;
      });
      console.log("Daily Visits Count Updated to " + dailyVisitsCount);

    });

  }
});
```

Any insight to why this block of code is not working the way it should that would be appreciates.

I did find out that this problem occurred due to a bug in a previous release of meteor which has been fixed.

I'm just trying to get today's date in a format my DB accepts and use that to filter my results. alternative suggestions is also welcomed.

PS: Momnet.js works for me in different locations(client side code)

---

EDIT:

```
W20180312-08:03:15.324(-7)? (STDERR) app/server/main.js:1
W20180312-08:03:15.325(-7)? (STDERR) (function(Npm,Assets){(function(){import moment from 'moment'
W20180312-08:03:15.325(-7)? (STDERR)                                   ^^^^^^
W20180312-08:03:15.325(-7)? (STDERR) 
W20180312-08:03:15.325(-7)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
W20180312-08:03:15.326(-7)? (STDERR)     at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
W20180312-08:03:15.327(-7)? (STDERR)     at /home/elder/Desktop/Recreation-of-ParkeyeDashboard/ParkeyeDashboard/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:289:30
W20180312-08:03:15.327(-7)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20180312-08:03:15.329(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/home/elder/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.4.2_3.14963jl++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20180312-08:03:15.330(-7)? (STDERR)     at /home/elder/Desktop/Recreation-of-ParkeyeDashboard/ParkeyeDashboard/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:128:5
W20180312-08:03:15.330(-7)? (STDERR)     at /home/elder/Desktop/Recreation-of-ParkeyeDashboard/ParkeyeDashboard/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:344:5
W20180312-08:03:15.330(-7)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/home/elder/Desktop/Recreation-of-ParkeyeDashboard/ParkeyeDashboard/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:480:12)
W20180312-08:03:15.331(-7)? (STDERR)     at /home/elder/Desktop/Recreation-of-ParkeyeDashboard/ParkeyeDashboard/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:343:11
```

Comment: How do you add moment package and how do you import it?

Comment: `meteor add momentjs:moment`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the moment.js package:

`meteor npm i --save moment`

Then at the top of your file you need to import moment:

`import moment from 'moment'`

Then to get the date in a format the DB will accept using moment just do:

`var date = moment().toDate()`

Using `moment()` creates a moment object of the current date/time. Running `toDate()` on it gives you the same date/time in a Date object.

Comment: thanks that worked, i just had to use `meteor add ecmascript` to be able to use import

Comment: @scriptkid no prob :)

Comment: Okay, so big problem here.
A. when I added `ecmascript` it broke my build for some reason.
B. when i dont have `ecmascript`, I get an error for `import moment from 'moment'` which renders most of my server side code useless. help please?

Comment: I recognise that name... you messaged me through my site, right? hey!
Ok, can you tell me what the error was?

Comment: Hey sean, yeah I contacted you through your site. please check my edit, it contains the new error I get

Comment: Can you re-add ecmascript and paste the error you have then?

Comment: Hey sean, I have no idea how or why, I just made a new project and copied my source then added each package one by one and things seem to work just fine.